# Redirecting users from India to a folder on server

Tags: magento

We have magento installed on our server. And there is a different website for the indian users. What we want is to redirect the indian audience to that. The indian website resides at **/in** folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If "Indian audience" means requests coming from IP addresses hosted by Indian ISPs:

You can try to locate the IP ranges yourself, by digging thru the free resources of the proper [RIR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regional_Internet_registry), which in case of India should be the [APNIC](http://www.apnic.net/publications/research-and-insights/ip-address-trends/by-rir).

You also could get the IP ranges directly from some commercial GeoIP/GeoLocation service, like e.g. [IP2Location](http://ip2location.com) or [MaxMind](http://maxmind.com). If you don't mind losing some accuracy, the latter also offers a free database download named [Geolite Country](http://www.maxmind.com/app/geolite).

After knowing the IP ranges, you can use them as rewrite conditions, e.g. in `RewriteCond` directives in the Magento root `.htaccess` file, or within Magento's `index.php` using `header()` commands.

`RewriteCond` example for two Indian IP ranges 58.2.0.0 to 58.2.255.255 and 61.0.0.0 to 61.0.255.255:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^58\.2\. [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^61\.0\.
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ in/$1 [R,L]
</IfModule>
```

Looking at the count and different types of Indian IP ranges and knowing that `mod_rewrite` does *not* support [CIDR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classless_Inter-Domain_Routing) notation for `RewriteCond` directives, I have no idea, whether or not it would be more performant to use `header()` redirects in Magento's `index.php` instead.

That said, be aware that redirecting based on IP addresses is not a perfect thing. There are thousands of [Open proxies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_proxy) available out there, hiding/obscuring the real IP address a request is coming from.